# Partition numbers as polynomial, each number in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm beginner at multithreading programming and I wanna write a piece of my code using it. I'm trying to split different numbers into multiple parts and store them as a polynomial. I wanna do this using multithreading as each number being splitted in one thread, all simultaneously. For example, 5 separate threads split 5 different numbers.

Suppose I have a class named `Polynomial`. Assume that there's just two numbers that I wanna create polynomials out of them. They are initialized and stored already and I wanna do the partition task on both of them simultaneously.

`Number` is a class that stores numbers. `n_Polynomial` and `m_Polynomial` store results. I created a method named `partitionNumbers()`.

```
Class Polynomial{
Number n,m,n_Polynomial[],m_Polynomial[],

private void partitionNumbers() {

        class Utility extends Thread {

            Number number; 
            Number parts[]; 
            boolean threadHasDoneTask = false;

            Utility(Number number) {
                this.number = number;
            }

            Number[] getParts() {
                return this.parts;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int partNumbers = (number.getReal().getIntegerPartLength() + number.getReal().getFractionalPartLength()) / base;
                if (partNumbers <= 1) {
                    partNumbers = 1;
                } else {
                    partNumbers++;
                }
                this.parts = new Number[partNumbers];
                String temp = this.number.toString();
                int index = temp.indexOf('.');
                if (index != -1) {
                    temp = new StringBuilder(temp).delete(index, index + 1).toString();
                }
                int length = temp.length();
                for (int i = partNumbers - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    try {
                        parts[i] = new Number(temp.substring(length - base, length));
                        length -= base;
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        parts[i] = new Number(temp.substring(0, length));
                    }
                }
                threadHasDoneTask = true;
                notify();
            }
        }

        Utility thread1 = new Utility(m);
        Utility thread2 = new Utility(n);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {
            while (!thread1.threadHasDoneTask) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        m_Polynomial = thread1.getParts();
        thread1.interrupt();
        try {
            while (!thread2.threadHasDoneTask) {
                wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        n_Polynomial = thread2.getParts();
        thread2.interrupt();
    }
}
```

I know using wait/notify idiom is wrong here, but I just can't find any other way to tell main thread that `thread1` and `thread2` are done!

What are my solution problems and is it generally reliable?

Comment: I wouldn't like to see a class definition inside a method.Just write the class declaration somewhere else

Comment: @cssGEEK `Utility` is just for calculations and only `partitionNumbers()` uses its instance. i'm not sure it is better to create a separate java file for it.